# Page of carousels - Skip links / best keyboard navigation

Tags: accessibility, keyboard, carousel

This question relates to UX with keyboard navigation and a11y for screen reader users.

We have an app that uses multiple carousels of movies, similar to Netflix or Disney+, with their respective category headings. It's difficult for users to navigate to different categories as they have to navigate through each item in each category. For example, to get to action they have to tab through 20 items to get to action. We are thinking about a skiplink menu with 2 different options below, any thoughts on these approaches or something different?

```
[skiplink menu here]

Comedy
[item] [item] [item] [item] [item] [next >]

Drama
[item] [item] [item] [item] [item] [next >]

Children
[item] [item] [item] [item] [item] [next >]

Suspense
[item] [item] [item] [item] [item] [next >]

Action
[item] [item] [item] [item] [item] [next >]
```

Should we be using a skiplink menu like:

```
Skip to 
- Comedy
- Drama
- Children
- Suspense
- Action
```

Or:

```
Skip to 
- Next category
- Previous category
```

Comment: Why is it difficult to make a choice between the two? If you can add the explanation for that to the question it would help get a useful answer. You have probably your concerns right, and are they based on more than what you did provide? Now can any answer only be based on a gut feeling or on a situation that is possibly completely different from yours.

Answer (score 1):

List the category options (Comedy, Drama, etc.) at the top.

You can use [ARIA labels](https://usability.yale.edu/web-accessibility/articles/links#aria) on the "Next" and "Previous" links to add more info just for screenreaders. A link could show as "Next" on the screen but read "Next: Comedy" on the screen reader.

Comment: I agree, one problem though is the length of this list will grow as new categories are added which means the user will have to go through a long list of links if they just want to browse the movies from top to bottom. It could end up being an oxymoron that we added a list to try and help browse faster that that slows them down by having to navigate through that list!

Comment: I am going to revise my answer with a little more information.